# Strange plot on a simple dataframe Rstudio

Tags: r, visualization, plotting, rstudio

I don't usually use R and I'm having trouble with a simple plot from a dataset. I just wanted to make a scatterplot and look at the values, but it keeps ploting a strange "box" thing which I don't really know if it's an error or if I'm missing data manipulation to make it work.

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("brunoruas2/gujarati", force=TRUE)
data(package = .packages(all.available = TRUE))
data(package = 'gujarati', Table3_6)

#Exercício 3.20

data(package = 'gujarati', Table3_6)
df <- Table3_6

#Nomes das colunas
names(df)[2] = 'Produçãox1'
names(df)[3] = 'Produçãox2'
names(df)[4] = 'Remuneraçãoy1'
names(df)[5] = 'Remuneraçãoy2'

summary(df)
View(df)

# Plot 1
plot(Remuneraçãoy1 ~ Produçãox1, data=df)
```

[image: This is the "strange" plot]

Comment: Either your data is not numerical, or you have many-to-many relationship between Remuneraçãoy1 and Produçãox1

Answer (score 1):

Update:
It was only a matter of transform string numbers in numerical numbers.

I did it by transforming each "non numeric" column in character and used the as.numeric().
The code looks like this now:

```
    #Nomes das colunas
names(df)[2] = 'Produçãox1'
names(df)[3] = 'Produçãox2'
names(df)[4] = 'Remuneraçãoy1'
names(df)[5] = 'Remuneraçãoy2'

df$Produçãox1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Produçãox1))
df$Produçãox2 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Produçãox2))
df$Remuneraçãoy1 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Remuneraçãoy1))
df$Remuneraçãoy2 <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Remuneraçãoy2))

#Regressão
reg1 <- lm(df$Remuneraçãoy1 ~ df$Produçãox1)
reg2 <- lm(df$Remuneraçãoy2 ~ df$Produçãox2)

#Plot
plot(df$Remuneraçãoy1 ~ df$Produçãox1,xlab='Produção do setor empresarial',
     ylab='Remuneração real')
abline(reg1, col='blue')

plot(df$Remuneraçãoy2 ~ df$Produçãox2,xlab='Produção do setor empresarial não agrícola',
     ylab='Remuneração real')
abline(reg2, col='red')
```